# Do Static Libraries need a PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file? or they use the App-Level one?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, static-libraries, privacy

I have a project that generates a fat Static Library (NOT a Static XC Framework), and the output of that project would be a single static library file let us say: "libProject.a"
We are distributing this "libProject.a" to our clients and we are not using XC Frameworks yet.

For this specific case of having Static Library, do we need PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file to be distributed with it? and in case it is required, how is it supposed to be distributed with the Static Library? is it enough for the ones who are using this library in their projects to add the missing XCPrivacy entries to their app "PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy" file ?

PS: I know ideally it would be better to use Static Framework instead of Static Library but that is still planned in our schedule for a future release, Since "Static Library" target type is still supported by Xcode 15.2 that means there must be a solution.

Comment: I'm also curious about this, but there's no clear answer.
Will adding it to the app's PrivacyInfo solve this problem?.. What should I do if I have to include it in the '.a'.. It's only a few days away, but why can't I see the exact answer..

Comment: No one has answered yet, and when I communicated with Apple about that they said: the only recommendation they have is to move to XC Static Framework instead of Static-Library target. There were many exchanges with Apple Code-Level-Support team and their answers were always the same, they have no solution for this. And it is not possible to add a privacy manifest file to a static library yet it is required. What I can tell is by experience adding it to the App Level Privacy Manifest works so far, but Apple told me that this is not correct and doesn't follow Apple requirements and may not pass.

Comment: Are you saying I can't use static libraries anymore? I can't understand Apple. Is there really no other way??

Comment: Unfortunately it is not me who is saying, it is Apple, I was as surprised as you, but who can change how Apple works? they support something and without deprecating it they make it impossible to use.

Answer (score 1):

If i submit an app without adding anything to 'PrivacyInfo'

I get an email saying that the APIs used by the static library (.a) are problematic.

And through this email, I added the contents to the app's 'PrivacyInfo'.

When I resubmitted it, I didn't get an e-mail.

For this policy to be meaningful

When creating and distributing static libraries, it seems good to distribute 'PrivacyInfo' content clearly to users.

If the API you use is a static library and an app at the same time, the contents of the library will be resolved automatically as the app developer adds the contents of the app.

Comment: This is what we get by experience and trial and error and that is what I tried to tell before based on my experience trying it, but what Apple says, this does not follow the rules and guidelines of the Privacy Manifest meaning to the customers thus it is not acceptable to them. Anyway I am writing this to tell that this is the only thing we can do for now, but it is not the right thing to do as per Apple requirements and guidelines based on their official confirmation during my discussion with them. So, I don't recommend going this way but short term it is good.